# How to delete lines having specific text using sed command?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I saw a similar Question on this forum but this question is little different from those questions. Hence please do not consider this as a duplicate.

I have a file containing data as

```
blah blah
blah blah Select from table blah blah QWERTY blah
Select from table
QWERTY Here
blah blah
```

Now I want to delete all the lines having both `Select from table` and `QWERTY`

Expected Output:

```
blah blah
Select from table
QWERTY Here
blah blah
```

I tried as below:

```
sed /*Select from table*QWERTY*/d file.txt
```

But it is not working. Could anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You was close with you `sed` attempt:

```
$ sed '/Select from table.*QWERTY/d' file
blah blah
Select from table
QWERTY Here
blah blah
```

You should always quotes the script with single quotes and don't confuse shell globbing with regular expressions. To match zero or more of any character using regular expressions is `.*`.

---

If order is guaranteed then a simply `grep` will do using the `-v` option:

```
$ grep -v 'Select from table.*QWERTY' file
blah blah
Select from table
QWERTY Here
blah blah
```

If order isn't guaranteed then used a language such as `awk` where you can combine regular expression matches with logical operators:

```
$ awk '!/Select from table/||!/QWERTY/' file
blah blah
Select from table
QWERTY Here
blah blah
```